# Displaying Alt + Number codes on HTML

Tags: html

I would like to write the character "▼" (Alt + 31) on HTML but it always shows me question mark.

What do I need to do in order to make my browser display it correctly ?

Thanks!

Comment: If it's a matter of configuring *your* browser (and it looks fine on mine) then it's not really a programming question.

Comment: you didnt understand me right. I can see the sign but when I type it into an HTML document and try to display that HTML file, it shows me qusetion mark

Comment: What, exactly, are you typing into your browser?

Comment: Basically im building a website and I would like to display the sign ▼, I just copy-paste it into my php page but it shows me question mark instead of the ▼ sign. I dont know why.

Comment: Likely just an encoding issue. How (in which encoding) are you saving the file?

Comment: You are right. I forgot to save the page as Unicode and that's why the sign didnt displayed correctly. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Use an HTML entity instead of copy and paste. The large down arrow is &#9660;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's probably an encoding problem. Your file is saved with a certain character encoding, but your browser displays it with another encoding — either because you didn't specify a charset in the header, or a different charset from the files charset.

One solution is to edit and save your files using UTF-8, and also add UTF-8 to the charset:

```
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
</head>
```

What's probably better though, is to use [HTML entities](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/sgml/entities.html). Example: `&copy;` becomes ©. You still need to specify the charset though, but this way you don't have to worry about saving your file the wrong way and losing all the special characters.

There are many lists ([random example](http://www.ascii.cl/htmlcodes.htm)) with all the available characters and their entities. However, not all characters have their own entity. For those you'll need to use their [Unicode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters) code. In this case you're looking for a "Black down-pointing triangle" which is `&#x25BC;` and becomes ▼.

Comment: I'll go against using HTML entities here. In the age of Unicode, there's no need to obfuscate your own source code and you'll need to worry about proper encoding either way.

Comment: @deceze: If you can be sure this never goes wrong, sure. But say you're using a different editor with different settings, or you're working on code with different people who might have applications that use different settings; a character encoding problem isn't that uncommon. So I prefer using entities whenever possible, and let the browser worry about displaying it correctly. To prevent obfuscation you can always add the real character or a description thereof as a comment in your code. That way you can still see what it is, but nothing can go wrong with the representation in the browser.

Comment: To that I say you have to worry about encoding anyway, and anybody who works on your code will have to as well. :) HTML entities are only a valid strategy if you're exclusively dealing with pure English. Any other case is unmaintainable using HTML entities, so you may as well invest the little bit of effort it takes to use Unicode end-to-end.

Comment: Whether it's English or not, texts don't belong within your code but in a database. A few characters here and there like arrows and bullets for layout purposes are fine, and those might as well be entities.